# Time zone conversion to CST based GMT offset

Tags: java, javascript, oracle, timezone, timezone-offset

I have date(01-oct-2014), time (00:37:31), GMT difference(-360) now 
I want to get the time conveted to CST. The solution can be in javascript
Or oracle databse.

I have read several articles but could'nt get any where..can some one help me out on this...

Comment: So what does Java have to do with it? And is that the local time or UTC? I suspect you don't *actually* want CST, but Central Time - which would currently be CDT.

Comment: So do you have a DATE column in the database containing date and time? Or do you have TIMESTAMP with or without timezone? If you have a DATE column (which does not have timezone information) and you know the "from" timezone, take a look at my blogpost here: http://dspsd.blogspot.dk/2012/02/date-and-dst.html - there is a function date_tz_convert() to convert to for example 'US/Central' (which is probably better than CST or CDT as it is daylight savings time aware :-)

Comment: @Kim - Yes, but preferably, use `'America/Chicago'`, not `'US/Central'` - which is a backwards compatibility link.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, to convert your local time to time of another timezone, you need to `CAST TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`.

For example, I want to convert 'IST' Indian standard time, i.e. my local timezone to 'CST', i.e. Central :

```
SQL> WITH T AS
  2    ( SELECT to_timestamp('10/01/2014 11','mm/dd/yyyy hh24') ist FROM dual
  3    )
  4  SELECT ist,
  5    CAST(CAST(ist AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) at TIME zone 'CST' AS TIMESTAMP) cst
  6  FROM t
  7  /

IST                                 CST
----------------------------------- ------------------------------
01-OCT-14 11.00.00.000000000 AM     01-OCT-14 12.30.00.000000 AM
```

Take care of `Daylight saving`. You might have to take care in understanding `CST` and `CDT`.

Comment: If you use a named timezone like 'US/Central' it automatically switches from CST to CDT and back at the correct dates in spring and fall.

Comment: I said to take care in **understanding** the difference ;-)

Comment: Yes of course ;-) I just wanted to be sure the OP didn't misunderstand thinking he needed to write `CASE WHEN IsSummerTime(THE_DATE) THEN 'CDT' ELSE 'CST' END` (assuming he has an IsSummerTime() function which will be pretty difficult to write ;-)

Comment: Good to see you have put some effort to leave no chance for OP or anybody to misunderstand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this:

```
SELECT 
    (TIMESTAMP '2014-10-01 00:37:31') AT TIME ZONE 'CST',
    FROM_TZ((TIMESTAMP '2014-10-01 00:37:31'), 'CST'),
    CAST((TIMESTAMP '2014-10-01 00:37:31') AT TIME ZONE 'CST' AS TIMESTAMP) 
FROM DUAL;
```

It depends if the result shall include the new time zone or not.