# How do I convert an oracle timestamp with time zone in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How do i convert an oracle 'timestamp with time zone' variable in PL/SQL from one timezone to another?
The variable is declared like this:

```
v_date timestamp with time zone;
```

This statement returns '-04:00' on my server:

```
select dbtimezone from dual;
```

For our example, the data in the variable is in 'EDT' ('-04:00') and I want to convert to an arbitrary time zone, such as 'EET' ('+02:00') and store it in a differnt variable:

```
v_date2 timestamp with time zone;
```

Comment: the answer you are looking for is here https://community.oracle.com/thread/1559211

Comment: Probably a duplicate question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134951/time-zone-conversion-to-cst-based-gmt-offset That makes two similar questions on same day :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert from one time zone to another with [`at time zone`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/expressions007.htm). For example:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  v_ts1  timestamp with time zone;
  v_ts2  timestamp with time zone;
begin
  v_ts1 := to_timestamp_tz('2014-10-01 13:00:00 US/Eastern',
    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR');
  v_ts2 := v_ts1 at time zone 'Europe/Athens';
  dbms_output.put_line(v_ts1 || ' => ' ||
    to_char(v_ts1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM'));
  dbms_output.put_line(v_ts2 || ' => ' ||
    to_char(v_ts2, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM'));
end;
/

01-OCT-14 13.00.00.000000 US/EASTERN => 2014-10-01 13:00:00 -04:00
01-OCT-14 20.00.00.000000 EUROPE/ATHENS => 2014-10-01 20:00:00 +03:00
```

You can use the hour and minute offsets instead, but using zone and region names means you don't have to account for daylight savings yourself. Even using EET gives you an odd result as it's still summertime in eastern Europe as well (EEST rather than EET), so while you said you wanted a +02:00 time, it really ought to be +03:00 for most of the period that the eastern US is on EDT rather than EST. (Though the clocks change on different dates, so it isn't always aligned or obvious which to use).

Letting Oracle worry about that is much simpler and safer, and as Wernfried said, it's better to not use the abbreviated names to avoid ambiguity and confusion - and even errors.

Comment: If you like to get an arbitrary time zone you should better not use the abbreviated time zone name, e.g. `EET` - they can be ambiguous and it will return an error. Use long region name instead, e.g. `Europe/Helsinki`. There are only a few time zones where you can use the abbreviated name, check by `SELECT * FROM v$timezone_names WHERE tzabbrev = tzname;`

Comment: Yep, I agree, and also for the same reason I said not to use the hour/minute offset. I just used EET because the OP referenced it and I was too lazy to look up a region in that zone...

Answer (score 0):

Try to extract timestamp components using [EXTRACT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions059.htm#SQLRF00639) function or TO_CHAR function. Then set appropriate value using [TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions214.htm#SQLRF06143) function